# Let Users and Clients share the same authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am using Laravel + Breeze. My App will have two access sites:

1. Admins can login related to the users table (working)
2. Clients can login related to the clients table (to be discussed)

I don't know, if this is a good idea, but I want to share the already implemented Auth Service with another Model: clients.

What I already implemented is:

- Logged in user can create a client
- Client receives a email verification email from an event
- Client can confirm email address and will be redirect to the login view

Now it becomes tricky for me. The `AuthenticatedSessionController::store()` method is checking for the `$request->authenticate()` and this runs agains the users table and fails for the clients table.
I slightly modified the method to redirect based on the type of login candidate:

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $request->authenticate();
        
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $user = User::where('id', Auth::id())->first();
        if ( $user ) {
            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        $client = Client::where('id', Auth::id())->findOrFail();
        if ( $client ) {
            return redirect()->to('portal.show', $client->id);
        }
    }
```

but this works for users only as `$request->authenticate()` will not let clients in.
Now I need support and from here on I'm just guessing that the next step is the update I did in `config/auth.php`:

```
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'clients' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Client::class,
        ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'clients' => [
            'provider' => 'clients',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],
    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to look into & modify `authenticate` method of `App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest` class.

One way of doing it could be to check for presence of `email` received via request against `users` and `clients` tables.

Then if the **email** belongs to a client - implement custom logic to validate credentials against `clients` table records and login the client

And if the **email** belongs to user - then let the request pass through as normal

Eg:

```php
public function authenticate()
{
    $type = DB::table('clients')->where('email', $this->email)->exists() ? 'client' : 'user';

    if($type === 'user') {
        return $this->authenticateUser();
    }

    //Validate credentials against `clients` table 
    // If valid retrieve the client and login the client 
    //Else throw ValidationException
}

//Copy the content of original authenticate to this method
protected function authenticateUser()
{

    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

    if (! Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
    RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}
```

**NOTE** With this approach you are not doing any rate-limiting/throttling nor firing attempt events

For complete robust authentication system for clients, I guess it will be required to define a separate guard, user provider and then re-implement `SessionGuard` functionality all over again.

Another wild thought which comes to mind is, why not have **Client** be represented as a record on `users` table just for authentication purpose and may be have a **one-to-one** relation between them.